# How to loop through json dictionary inside of list

Tags: python, json, loops

I am doing web scraping, and I got data in a json object that looks like this:

```
{'categories': '[{"title":"Name", "desc":"Mike"}, {"title":"Food", "desc":"Muffin"}]'}
```

And I want to loop through this dictionary and just get one value "Muffin".
My code is:

```
for item in the_dict:
    for i in range(0, len(item)-1):
        muff_filter = json.loads(the_dict['categories'])[i]['title']    
        if muff_filter == 'Food':
            print(json.loads(the_dict['categories'])[i]['desc'])
        else:
            pass
```

I get expected output, however I keep getting the error:

```
Muffin
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-9a650257d42a> in <module>
     61     for item in the_dict:
     62         for i in range(0, len(item)-1):
---> 63             food_filter = json.loads(the_dict['categories'])[i]['title']
     64             if food_filter == 'Food':
     65                 print(json.loads(the_dict['categories'])[i]['desc'])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried enumerating the list but still get the same error, and also tried using a key, value pair but the same error. Can you give me an idea where I'm thinking wrong?

+++ So I have run %xmode Verbose according to the suggestion in the comment,
and I got the following error:

```
Muffin
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-e1844b3cae82> in <module>
     61     for item in get_cert:
     62         for i in range(0, len(item)-2):
---> 63             the_dict= json.loads(the_dict['categories'])[i]['title']

        global get_cert = {'categories': '[{"title":"Name","desc":"Mike"},{"title":"Food","desc":"Muffin"}]'}
        global i = 2
     64             if muff_filter == 'Food':
     65                 print(json.loads(the_dict['categories'])[i]['desc'])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `item` is a dictionaries key, not the length of whichever category you're loading

Comment: Is the value in the dictionary["categories"] a string?

Comment: Put a print statement at line 62.5 and display i along with the intermediate values of the_dict to see where it fails.

Comment: @Filip It looks like a string, as the value is inside ' '.

Comment: Run a cell with `%xmode Verbose` and then you will see variables in your traceback.

Comment: So you can't loop through it and get the whole word `"Muffin"`. You can only get a character of it. So you can just check if the word `"Muffin"` is in that string. `if "Muffin" in the_dict["categories"]: # do things`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Do you know how to use dictionaries and lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple blobs of json data in `the_dict` iterate over each blob:

```
for jsondata in the_dict.values(): 
    for d in json.loads(jsondata):
        if d.get('title') == 'Food':
            print(d['desc'])
```

or if you know there is only one blob of json data in `the_dict` and it's under the key `'categories'`:

```
for d in json.loads(the_dict['categories']):
    if d.get('title') == 'Food':
        print(d['desc'])
```

Comment: It worked!!! I used the first method, why do you think my code was not working??

Comment: @sarahkim: It didn't work because `for item in the_dict:` iterates over the keys of `the_dict`.  There is only on key and it is `'categories'`.  `for i in range(0, len(item)-1):` just does `for i in range(0, len('categories')-1):` which is pointless.  Also, iterating over an index is generally an anti-pattern in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, values in the_dict.items():
    jvalues = json.loads(values)
    for val in jvalues:
        muff_filter = json.loads(val)['title']    
        if muff_filter == 'Food':
            print(json.loads(val)['desc'])
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Yes I know it is loaded as a json with `jvalues = json.loads(values)`

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.